# Expand a div that has a preview of its contents using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have to display 5 lines of text, one below another like so:

1) Line one 
2) Line two 
3) Line three 
4) Line four 
5) Line five

but with a special requirement of displaying only the first 2 lines, and have some kind of jquery magic that would hide lines 3->5 and display them when the user clicks the down arrow or similar control. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: SO is not do-the-job site. Post your effort in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this :
HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class="line">Line one</li>
   <li class="line">Line two</li>
   <li class="line">Line three</li>
   <li class="line">Line four</li>
   <li class="line">Line five</li>
   <li class="showMore">Show More</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.line:nth-child(n+3) {
   display:none;
}
.showMore{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:12px;
  color:blue;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showMore').click(function() {
      $('ul li:gt(1)').show();
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: I has no idea I could do it with CSS like you suggested. Thanks for a brilliant suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do in 2 ways. 
1- just show 2 lines and a trigger "more" on clicking More, load rest of 3 lines using jquery and show all 5.

2- print all 5 but set the height of div to present only 2. on clicking more change height like from 25px to 100px.